# Primary Key Data Annotation of EntityFrameworkcore.sqlite is not working

Tags: uwp, entity-framework-core, primary-key, data-annotations

i have an UWP-Project collecting some data and i want to save them into a database.
I created a .net Libary with EntityFrameworkcore sqlite.

im creating the DBContext:

```
public class DBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<MyModel> Model { get; set; }


    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=MyModel.db");
    }
}
```

And MyModel class Contains following code:

```
public class MyModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id;}
```

Now im calling from my UWP-Project just the DatabaseContext to store my data:

```
    public static class DatabaseService
{
    public static void SaveToDb(DataList model)
    {
        using (var db = new DBContext())
        {
            foreach(var auction in model.auctions)
            {
                MyModel data = new MyModel() { Id = model.Id};
                db.Model.Add(data);
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

But he still complains that MyModel doesent have a definition for a PrimaryKey.

Do i miss something that it is recognizing the Key Anotation for PrimaryKey?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key needs to be a property, not a field.

```cs
public class MyModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id {get;set;}
}
```